# Can I change the name of the Configuration file when I enable migrations in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have more than one context, and I need to enable migrations for them, Is there a way to give a name for each Configuration file, when I run this command:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext
```

Comment: is `-MigrationsDirectory` what you are looking for?

Comment: It seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-MigrationsDirectory` to put the migration tree into a sub folder in your project. This should allow you to have 2 separate configuration files in the same project for two separate configs.

Alternately you can use `-ProjectName` and put each context into its own separate project

You can use tab complete (`Enable-Migrations -<Tab>`) to check out all of the options for enable-migrations